# Riesz Representation Theorem for bounded linear operators rather than functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4233743/two-notions-of-a-pure-state/4233861#4233861) a few days ago and I got a very nice answer. However, it led me to another question regarding the mentioned Riesz Representation Theorem for bounded linear operators instead of bounded linear functionals. The result I know states that to every bounded linear functional (i.e. taking values on the field) $f$ one can associate an element $\psi \in \mathscr{H}$ such that $f(\varphi) = \langle \psi, \varphi\rangle$ holds for every $\varphi \in \mathscr{H}$. However, I have never seen such a result for bounded linear operators. The answer to my previous question claims that if $T$ is a bounded linear operator on $\mathscr{H}$, there exists $\varphi,\psi \in \mathscr{H}$ such that for every $\eta \in \mathscr{H}$ one has $T(\eta) = \langle \psi, \eta\rangle \varphi$. In addition, if $T$ is self-adjoint, then $\psi = \varphi$.  Why does the latter holds? Does this result follow from the "usual" Riesz Representation Theorem for functionals somehow?

Comment: If rank of $T$ is greater than one, this is obviously false.